# How to apply a function to each element in a list, then make a list of the outputs?

Tags: python, list, prime-factoring

Im trying to get **prime factors** by factorizing a number and adding the factors to `list1`, and then factorizing every number in `list1` using the same method from before and adding to `list2`, so any prime factor will have a list length of `2` (If the number is a square number it prints out the square root twice, but since it is not a prime, it doesn't matter).

I don't know how to get it to apply my factors() function to every element in the `list1` and make a list of all the factorized factors I've made.

```py
import math
list1 = []
list2 = []
def factors(num1):

    for x in range(1, int(math.sqrt(num1) + 1)):
        if num1 % x == 0:
            list2.append(int(x))
            list2.append(int(num1/x))
            list2.sort()

print("enter a number:")
number = int(input())

for m in range(1, int(math.sqrt(number) + 1)):
    if number % m == 0:
        list1.append(int(m))
        list1.append(int(number/m))
        list1.sort()

for y in list1:
    factors(y)
print(list2)
```

desired output
if 20 was the input

```
((1,1),(1,2),(1,2,2,4)(1,5),(1,2,5,10),(1,2,4,5,10,20))
```

Comment: Can you show for example what you want the output to look like? Do you want a nested list of factors for each value, or what?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `factors` function, you are appending the factors themselves to `list2` but as you want nested list of factors, you should create another list and append that to `list2` instead. Changed code would look something like this.

```
import math
list1 = []
list2 = []
def factors(num1):
    factor_list = []
    for x in range(1, int(math.sqrt(num1) + 1)):
        if num1 % x == 0:
            factor_list.append(int(x))
            factor_list.append(int(num1/x))
    factor_list.sort()
    list2.append(factor_list)

print("enter a number:")
number = int(input())

for m in range(1, int(math.sqrt(number) + 1)):
    if number % m == 0:
        list1.append(int(m))
        list1.append(int(number/m))
        list1.sort()

for y in list1:
    factors(y)
print(list2)
```

Also, since you've already wrote the `factors` function, you can use it for factorizing the input number itself instead of writing the same code again. So a better version of the same code is:

```
import math


def factors(num1):
    factor_list = []
    for x in range(1, int(math.sqrt(num1) + 1)):
        if num1 % x == 0:
            factor_list.append(int(x))
            factor_list.append(int(num1/x))
    factor_list.sort()
    return factor_list

print("enter a number:")
number = int(input())

list1 = factors(number)
list2 = [factors(x) for x in list1]

print(list2)
```

Following up on the comment, if you want to include only on those elements which have length 2, you can use another list comprehension for that:

```
list2 = [x for x in list2 if len(x)==2]
```

Comment: how would i add an if statement to the end of that so it only gives when the list length is 2?

Comment: @aloofbay Can you please elaborate or give an example? I didn't understand your followup question.

Comment: well because all the prime numbers have a list length of 2 i tried to write                 for y in list1:
    factors(y)
    if len(list2) == 2:
        print(list2) but it didnt work

Comment: Okay. For that you can filter `list2` to include only those elements which have length 2. I will update my answer to include this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using list comprehension like so. I modified the `factors` function slightly to return the list.

```py
import math

def factors(num):
     fact = []
     for x in range(1, int(math.sqrt(num)+1)):
         if num % x == 0:
             fact.append(x)
             fact.append(int(num/x))
     fact.sort()
     return fact

print("enter a number:")
number = int(input())

list1 = factors(number)
list2 = [factors(f) for f in list1]
```

Result for 20:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 4], [1, 5], [1, 2, 5, 10], [1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20]]
```